# Calculating rolling average per group in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df` like this:

```
date        car     model       mpg
1           ford    focus       10
1           ford    fiesta      15
1           ford    mustang     20
2           ford    focus       13
2           ford    fiesta      16
2           ford    mustang     27
3           ford    focus       13
3           ford    mustang     27
4           ford    focus       12
4           ford    fiesta      17
```

I would like to add a column `rolling_mean` with `window = 2` of `date` per group of `date, car, model` so that I would have a df like this:

```
date        car     model       mpg     rolling_avg
1           ford    focus       10      nan
1           ford    fiesta      15      nan
1           ford    mustang     20      nan
2           ford    focus       13      11.5
2           ford    fiesta      16      15.5
2           ford    mustang     27      23.5
3           ford    focus       13      13
3           ford    mustang     27      27
4           ford    focus       12      12.5
4           ford    fiesta      17      Because fiesta is not in date=3, I want to (17+0)/2 = 8.5
```

What I tried:

```
df_test.groupby(['date','car','model'])[['mpg']].rolling(window=2).mean().reset_index()
```

```
    date    car model   level_3 mpg
0   1   ford    fiesta  1       NaN
1   1   ford    focus   0       NaN
2   1   ford    mustang 2       NaN
3   2   ford    fiesta  4       NaN
4   2   ford    focus   3       NaN
5   2   ford    mustang 5       NaN
6   3   ford    focus   6       NaN
7   3   ford    mustang 7       NaN
8   4   ford    fiesta  9       NaN
9   4   ford    focus   8       NaN
```

Not sure what does `level_3` stand for. Where is my mistake in trying to achieve the structure I desire?

Here is the data used:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4],
                   'car':['ford','ford','ford','ford','ford','ford','ford','ford','ford','ford'],
                   'model':['focus','fiesta','mustang','focus','fiesta','mustang','focus','mustang','focus','fiesta'],
                   'mpg':[10,15,20,13,16,27,13,27,12,17]})
```

Comment: dont group by date. you only have one model per date. so you only get groups of size 1. simply use `df.groupby(['car','model'])[['mpg']].rolling(window=2).mean().reset_index()`

Comment: Isn't the problem simply that you are grouping the DataFrame by **date, car and model** while it only should be grouped on **car and model**? By grouping it by date, car and model, each row itself is a single group and that is why you are receiving NaN values.

Comment: That makes sense, however, I want the `date` present so that I could draw a graph by date of how rolling average changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me working reshape value first by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html), if no match is added `0`, then use `rolling` and last reshape back by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and add new column by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
s = (df.set_index(['date','car','model'])['mpg']
        .unstack(fill_value=0)
        .rolling(window=2)
        .mean()
        .stack()
        .rename('rolling_avg')
        )

df = df.join(s, on=['date','car','model'])
print (df)
   date   car    model  mpg  rolling_avg
0     1  ford    focus   10          NaN
1     1  ford   fiesta   15          NaN
2     1  ford  mustang   20          NaN
3     2  ford    focus   13         11.5
4     2  ford   fiesta   16         15.5
5     2  ford  mustang   27         23.5
6     3  ford    focus   13         13.0
7     3  ford  mustang   27         27.0
8     4  ford    focus   12         12.5
9     4  ford   fiesta   17          8.5
```

EDIT: If `set_index` with `unstack` fialed, there are duplicates like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4],
                   'car':['ford','ford','ford','ford','ford','ford','ford','ford','ford','ford'],
                   'model':['focus','focus','mustang','focus','focus','mustang','focus','mustang','focus','fiesta'],
                   'mpg':[10,15,20,13,16,27,13,27,12,17]})

print (df)
   date   car    model  mpg
0     1  ford    focus   10 <- dupe 1  ford    focus
1     1  ford    focus   15 <- dupe 1  ford    focus
2     1  ford  mustang   20
3     2  ford    focus   13 <- dupe 2  ford    focus
4     2  ford    focus   16 <- dupe 2  ford    focus
5     2  ford  mustang   27
6     3  ford    focus   13
7     3  ford  mustang   27
8     4  ford    focus   12
9     4  ford   fiesta   17
```

Then if possible first need unique pairs, here by aggregation `sum` (or `mean` like need):

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(index=['date','car'], 
                     columns='model', 
                     values='mpg', 
                     aggfunc='sum', 
                     fill_value=0)
print (df1)
model      fiesta  focus  mustang
date car                         
1    ford       0     25       20
2    ford       0     29       27
3    ford       0     13       27
4    ford      17     12        0
```

And then is possible use `rolling`, output is different like input data, because unique `'date','car','model'`:

```
df1 = (df1.rolling(window=2)
        .mean()
        .stack(dropna=False)
        .rename('rolling_avg')
        .reset_index()
        )

print (df1)
  
    date   car    model  rolling_avg
0      1  ford   fiesta          NaN
1      1  ford    focus          NaN
2      1  ford  mustang          NaN
3      2  ford   fiesta          0.0
4      2  ford    focus         27.0
5      2  ford  mustang         23.5
6      3  ford   fiesta          0.0
7      3  ford    focus         21.0
8      3  ford  mustang         27.0
9      4  ford   fiesta          8.5
10     4  ford    focus         12.5
11     4  ford  mustang         13.5
```

Comment: Thanks, however, when I use it on my `df` I get `Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape` at line `.unstack(fill_value=0)`. Do you know what might cause this? I do have repeating entries in all columns, although the same as in my example `df ` above.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - added possible solution, but need aggregate, not sure if possible use for you. If not, what should be expected output from changed sample data in my `EDIT` ?

Comment: Thank you, as always.